# hydrogenation using H2 + Ni2B

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I am having trouble understanding why hydrogenation with $\ce{Ni2B}$ gives anti-addition.
all my book says is this:

[image]

Could someone explain the mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your book says wrong **Ni<sub>2</sub>B** (P-2 Catalyst) is used as a surface for the reaction to take place (as it contains free electrons).
The **H<sub>2</sub>** is adsorbed by the surface of **Ni<sub>2</sub>B**. Similarly the molecules of alkyne are adsorbed by surface of **Ni<sub>2</sub>B**. Slowly stepwise the **adsorbed hydrogen** and the **adsorbed alkyne** forms bond and **syn-addition** takes place before the organic molecule leaves the catalyst surface. As a consequence, both hydrogen atoms usually add from the same side of molecule which results in formation of  **cis-alkene (or Z-alkene)**.

Similar reaction is hydrogenation of alkene using Pt as catalyst, it is also syn addition.

See [adsorption on wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adsorption)
Also [Reaction on surfaces Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactions_on_surfaces)